# Is GR the only theory in physics which cares about absolute energy?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-field-theory, energy, cosmology, vacuum

In my QFT course, they justify dropping the vacuum energy as 'physics only cares about *relative* energies except for GR in the stress-energy tensor'.

Is this strictly true?